# Exclude certain keyword from URL

Tags: python, html, regex

I am successfully able to get the url using my technique but point is that i need to change the url slightly like this: "http://www.example.com/static/p/no-name-0330-227404-1.jpg". Where as in img tag i get this link: "http://www.example.com/static/p/no-name-0330-227404-1-product.jpg"

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="swiper-wrapper"><img data-error-placeholder="PlaceholderPDP.jpg" class="swiper-lazy swiper-lazy-loaded" src="http://www.example.com/static/p/no-name-0330-227404-1-product.jpg"></div>
```

Python Code:

```
imagesList = []
imagesList.append([re.findall(re.compile(u'http.*?\.jpg'), etree.tostring(imagesList).decode("utf-8")) for imagesList in productTree.xpath('//*[@class="swiper-wrapper"]/img')])

print (imagesList)
```

output:

```
[['http://www.example.com/static/p/no-name-8143-225244-1-product.jpg']]
```

**NOTE:** I need to remove "-product" from url and I have no idea why this url is inside two square brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are intending to remove just the product keyword then you can simply use the .replace() API. Otherwise you can construct regular expressions to manipulate the string. Below is an example code for the replace API.

```
myURL = "http://www.example.com/static/p/no-name-0330-227404-1-product.jpg"
myURL = myURL.replace("-product", "") # gives u "http://www.example.com/static/p/no-name-0330-227404-1.jpg"
print(myURL)
```

**Regular expression version**: (Probably not a clean solution, as in it is difficult to understand). However it is better than the first approach because it dynamically discard the last set of -words (e.g. -product)

What I have done is capture 3 parts of the URL but omit the middle part because that is the -product bit, and combine part 1 and 3 together to form your URL.

```
import re
myURL = "http://www.example.com/static/p/no-name-0330-227404-1-product.jpg"

myPattern = "(.*)(-.*)(\.jpg)$"
pattern = re.compile(myPattern)
match = re.search(pattern, myURL)
print (match.group(1) + match.group(3))
```

Same output as above:
http://www.example.com/static/p/no-name-0330-227404-1.jpg

Comment: Your solution is correct but how do i put it inside my new format, please see new python code.

Comment: I don't have the full script so it is kinda difficult for me to help you. You can try breaking down that 1 liner into 2 parts by removing the image.append API and that nested square brackets [] and see what it gives you. Something like. 

re.findall(re.compile(u'http.*?\.jpg'), etree.tostring(imagesList).decode("utf-8"))
 for imagesList in productTree.xpath('//*[@class="swiper-wrapper"]/img')

Comment: If it is giving you that string you posted then inject my code to manipulate the string and then append the processed url into the imageList.

Answer (score 0):

If all the images have the word "product" could you just do a simple string replace and remove just that word? Whatever you are trying to do (including renaming files) I see that as the simplest solution.